# How to share a Renderscript allocation with OpenGL in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, renderscript

I have a Renderscript which processes an image that is given in output to an Allocation.
I want to use this Allocation as a texture in my OpenGL program but I don't know how to get a texture ID from the Allocation.

On the other hand, I know I could use a graphic Renderscript, but since it has been deprecated, I guess there must be some other way to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 7):

Specify USAGE_IO_OUTPUT when you create the Allocation. Assuming you are generating the texture data in a script you would also add USAGE_SCRIPT.  You can then call

Allocation.setSurface(theGLSurface)

to link the allocation to a texture.  Each time you want to update the texture with the contents of the script you need to call.

Allocation.ioSend()

This will move the data without making extra copies.

Comment: So, I guess I have to do a `Allocation.setSurface(new Surface(new SurfaceTexture(textureID)))` in order to bind the allocation of the output to the texture ID. I'm running the script and then rendering the texture to the screen, but I cannot see any change in the rendering, as the script was never run

Comment: I tried this but it would cause a crash when the Renderscript context was released, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842609/how-to-tidy-up-a-surface-and-surfacetexture-when-used-with-renderscript

Answer (score 2):

You have phrased the question in terms of transforming an Allocation into 
a texture, but it's easier to think of creating a texture then granting
the Allocation ownership of that texture. This way, you would know the
texture ID before passing it to the Allocation. Beware: the Allocation
has the power to [radically change](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/Allocation.html#USAGE_IO_OUTPUT) properties of the texture.

### Step by step:

1. Create a GL texture
2. Create a [SurfaceTexture using its ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html#SurfaceTexture%28int%29)
3. Create an Allocation with usage `Allocation.USAGE_IO_OUTPUT | Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT`
4. Pass the SurfaceTexture to the Allocation with `setSurface()`
5. Put data in the Allocation
6. Call `ioSend()` on the Allocation to update the texture
7. Repeat steps 5 and 6 as often as you want to update the texture

I am very far from a GL expert, so step 2 is frankly conjecture.
Below is an adaptation of the HelloCompute sample in which I replace
`displayout` with a [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html), 
which is a View that handily creates a texture and a SurfaceTexture for me.
From then on I follow the steps above.

```
package com.example.android.rs.hellocompute;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.renderscript.Allocation;
import android.renderscript.Element;
import android.renderscript.RenderScript;
import android.renderscript.Type;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.Surface.OutOfResourcesException;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class HelloCompute extends Activity {
    private Bitmap mBitmapIn;

    private RenderScript mRS;
    private ScriptC_mono mScript;
    private Allocation mSurfaceAllocation;
    private Allocation mCanvasAllocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mBitmapIn = loadBitmap(R.drawable.data);
        int x = mBitmapIn.getWidth();
        int y = mBitmapIn.getHeight();

        ImageView in = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.displayin);
        in.setImageBitmap(mBitmapIn);

        mRS = RenderScript.create(this);
        mScript = new ScriptC_mono(mRS, getResources(), R.raw.mono);

        mCanvasAllocation = Allocation.createTyped(mRS, 
                new Type.Builder(mRS, Element.RGBA_8888(mRS))
                    .setX(x).setY(y).create(), 
                Allocation.USAGE_IO_INPUT | Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

        mSurfaceAllocation = Allocation.createTyped(mRS, 
                new Type.Builder(mRS, Element.RGBA_8888(mRS))
                    .setX(x).setY(y).create(), 
                Allocation.USAGE_IO_OUTPUT | Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

        TextureView mTextureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.displayout);
        mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(
          new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture s, 
                    int w, int h) {
                if(s != null) mSurfaceAllocation.setSurface(new Surface(s));
                mScript.forEach_root(mCanvasAllocation, mSurfaceAllocation);
                mSurfaceAllocation.ioSend();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture s, 
                    int w, int h) {
                if(s != null) mSurfaceAllocation.setSurface(new Surface(s));
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture s) {
                mSurfaceAllocation.setSurface(null);
                return true;
            }
        });

        try {
            Surface surface = mCanvasAllocation.getSurface();
            Canvas canvas = surface.lockCanvas(new Rect(0,0,100,100));
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapIn, 0, 0, new Paint());
            surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            mCanvasAllocation.ioReceive();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OutOfResourcesException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Bitmap loadBitmap(int resource) {
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resource, options);
    }
}
```