# Does NDK RenderScript support texture access?

Tags: android-ndk, renderscript

The Java API allows a RenderScript Allocation to function as a [SurfaceTexture provider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/Allocation.html#USAGE_IO_INPUT).
(Simple usage [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22057676/1836590))

The C++ API seems to support only half of the methods necessary to bind an Allocation to a texture. Specifically, in [rsCppStructs.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/rs/+/master/cpp/rsCppStructs.h) (lines 278-569) the following methods are defined:

```
void syncAll(RsAllocationUsageType srcLocation);
void ioSendOutput();
void ioGetInput();
```

but the methods `setSurface` and `getSurface` are absent. Has that functionality not yet been implemented? If not, when might it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not at the moment. the issue is actually with the underlying support library and how surface textures work across different Android versions than anything specifically about the NDK bindings. it's on our list of things to do in the near future, but I can't give a real ETA.

Comment: Can you point me to a resource describing the differences between surface texture operation?

Comment: the lack of documentation describing the differences is why it's taking a while. essentially, the platform APIs we rely on for SurfaceTexture operation in libRS aren't present in the NDK, so we have to do something using an entirely different set of APIs for libRSSupport.